# The theory of (Z, s) has quantifier elimination

Tags: proof-verification, logic, first-order-logic, model-theory, quantifier-elimination

Let $T = \text{Th}(\mathbb{Z}, s)$ where $s$ is the successor function. I want to show quantifier elimination (QE) for $T$ and construct a concrete $\omega$-saturated model. However, I am unsure whether my approach to such problems is correct/efficient and with the right level of detail.

My idea: we use that $T$ has QE iff every local isomorphism (with finite domain) from a model of $T$ to an $\omega$-saturated model of $T$ can be extended with a single element. To extend the local isomorphism $f : \{m_1, \dots, m_k\} \subset M \to N$ with $m \in M$, it suffices to find $f(m) \in N$ such that the $\text{dist}(m_i, m) = \text{dist}(f(m_i), f(m))$ for all $i \in \{1, \dots, k\}$. Here $\text{dist}(a, b)$ is defined as the number of +1 steps between $a$ and $b$, which is possibly infinite. Two observations:

1. Finite distances are easily matched because every model of $T$ locally looks like $\mathbb{Z}$.
2. $\omega$-saturated models of $T$ have an infinite subset of elements at infinite distance from each other. Therefore, as only finitely many elements are considered, infinite distances can also be matched.

This established QE for $T$. Using QE we immediately see that the model of countable many copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ is $\omega$-saturated.

I have the same question for the theory $T = \text{Th}(\mathbb{Z}, <, s)$, but its analysis appears to me identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument looks correct to me. In the case of $\text{Th}(\mathbb{Z},<,s)$, Case 2 is a bit more complicated, since "infinite distance" isn't enough. You also need to ensure that the order relation is preserved. So you need to argue that in an $\omega$-saturated model, the set of $\mathbb{Z}$-chains is ordered like a dense linear order without endpoints.

Comment: With regard to $\text{Th}(\mathbb{Z}, <, s)$ I indeed missed the density condition you need on the $\mathbb{Z}$-chains! But that's immediate from the $\omega$-saturation assumption. Do you think my argument is sufficiently well formulated? I feel it might be too hand-wavy, especially without drawing pictures. Thanks for your all your help!

Comment: Your argument seems sufficiently clear to me. But how detailed an argument needs to be depends entirely on the audience (and the author). At the very least, you should make sure that you are totally convinced that the argument is correct. Then, you should consider the expectations and background of the person(s) who will be reading your proof.

Comment: Am I correct that $\text{RM}(\text{Th}(\mathbb{Z}, <, s)) = \omega$?

Comment: The Morley rank is $\infty$, which is different from $\omega$. Morley rank $\infty$ means that the Morley rank is greater than $\alpha$ for all ordinals $\alpha$. Equivalently, the theory is not $\omega$-stable.

Comment: Okay, yes I see. My intuition is completely wrong here. So far I've imagined the Morley rank of a unary formula $\varphi(x)$ to be the "height" of an $\omega$-branching tree, where each node is associated to a subset of the model $M$. These sets are under the conditions that 1) the set associated to the root is $\{m \in M : M \models \varphi(m)\}$; 2) the set of a child is a subset of the partent; 3) siblings have disjoint sets; 4) no set is empty.

Comment: @Ibrahim That intuition is correct for finite Morley rank. And if you have such a tree of infinite height, you have Morley rank $\infty$. The way you get infinite ordinal-valued Morley rank is by having trees of arbitrary finite height, but no tree of infinite height.

Comment: I think I sort of get it; the crux is that the formulas in the arbitrary large finite trees are allowed to vary with height, whereas this is not so for infinite trees. But what is counter intuitive (to me) is that we continue to look at trees of arbitrary finite height, even for ordinals like $\omega_1$, or way bigger. Maybe some examples will help. Can every ordinal occur as a Morley rank? Is it hard to find such theories (maybe this is more suitable for a new question)? In particular I would like to see theories for $\text{RM} = \omega, \omega+1, \omega_1$.

Comment: And as always: your help is very highly valued! I really mean that.

Comment: If you have more general questions about Morley rank, I think you should ask a new question.

Comment: I've posted it now as a separate question, and included there some additional thoughts about the intuition of Morley rank.